# How to get an AJAX response from controller to jsp

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring boot application, I want to make a call from the search page(jsp) to controller, fetch the response and update in the jsp by AJAX. Right now on making a submit call, I get nothing. (to add, if I make a rest api call to controller I get a response from db i.e. http://localhost:8080/problems/{problemId}). Basically I need to know how to combine the response from ui to api. Please suggest if any mapping or bind varibles to be added.

my jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ include file = "header.jsp" %>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h1>Lookup from Oracle database</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
        <h2>${message}</h2>

        <td>Search Category:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="searchcategories">
            <option value="-1">-Select Category-</option>
            <option value="problem">problem</option>
            <option value="attachment">attachment</option>
            <option value="tstt">tstt</option>  
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>Entity Id:</td>
        <input type="text" name="problemId" id="search_data"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search problem no..">
        <button type="submit" id="submit_btn" onclick="">Search</button>

        </div>
    </div>

    <%@ include file = "footer.jsp" %>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
     {
     $('#submit_btn').click(function(){
    var problemId = $('#search_data').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        url : "http://localhost:8080/problems/" + problemId,
        success : function(data) {
            /* $("#response").html(data);  */
            var parsed_data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(parsed_data.success);
        }

    });
    return data;
    });
    });

    $("form").submit(function(){
          alert("Submitted");
        });


</script>
</html>
```

my controller class (gives response when I call directly through rest i.e. http://localhost:8080/problems/{problemId}):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/problems")
public class BugController {

    @Autowired
    BugRepository problemRepository; 

    @GetMapping("/{problemId}")
     public Bug getProblemById(@PathVariable Long problemId) {
      return problemRepository.findByProblemId(problemId);
     }
}
```

Expecting jsp to make a call to controller, by sending paramter being searched and render the response back to jsp
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASitF.png)

[image]

Comment: Does your network tab show the call being made? One more thing is that your ajax call is not being used in anyway

Comment: This is what I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()" on hitting the submit button in the inspect element. I am not a UI expert but was working on some POC. Let me know a bit more on what should I be doing.

Comment: I am able to make a call to controller but not getting response back rendered, please suggest (i guess it has to do something with return ):         $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     dataType : "json",
     url : "http://localhost:8080/problems/" + problemId,
     success : function(data) {
            $("#response").html(data);
        }

 });
 return data;

Comment: Update your post above with your updated and structured code. Does problem ID get properly set prior to the Ajax call?

Comment: HI Edwin, updated the code in main section, not able to formate by hitting "ENTER" in comments....anyways I am getting some script error, call is going to db and executing hibernating query, I am able to response with postman. Added image of the issue,                                                                          
        "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data"     &        "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object""

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not recommended to have any HTML code outside of the **head** and **body** tags, except the **doctype** and the **html** wrapper element. This can cause unexpected problems.

The jQuery **ajax** method parameter object supports the callback properties *success*, *error* and *complete*. At the moment your code seems to start an AJAX request to your backend, but it does not handle the response data.

[Here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is a link to the jQuery **ajax** method documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your uploaded image shows error status 500(internal server error). This means **something wrong with your server side code.** Maybe there is a problem with your database find query for example. The exception stacktrace can help you to debug and find server side problem.

But there is also a client side problem with your ajax code. You should use this pattern for sending rest ajax request to the server:

```
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    type: "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    url : "http://localhost:8080/problems/" + problemId
    success: function(data) {
       //data is in json format. You can log it and use it's properties.
    }
});
```

Comment: HI Hemed, updated the code in main section, not able to formate by hitting "ENTER" in comments....anyways I am getting some script error, call is going to db and executing hibernating query, I am able to response with postman. Added image of the issue,                                                                          
        "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data"     &        "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object""